# Starting Python tutorials but have some beginner questions

Tags: python, django, powershell

Hello I am attempting to learn Python using django in powershell on windows to create a simple CRUD app but have some questions regarding the setup and usage.

I have setup the path environment variable to include paths to a folder that includes test .py scripts that I thought allowed me to run directly from a c:\ in powershell but when I try to run the samples using:

```
c:\> python test1.py
c:\> python .\test1.py
```

It does not work and I get:

c:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '.\test1.py':[Errno 2] No such file or directory

but if I CD to path first and run it works fine and I get the output in the powershell window itself:

```
c:\> cd c:\Python27\Scripts
c:\Python27\Scripts> python test1.py
```

In addition if I just type the name of the script from the root c:\ prompt such as:

```
c:\> c:\Python27\Scripts\test1.py
c:\> test1.py
```

it runs the script by opening in a dos box that that closes immediately since it ran the script and finished.

What is the difference between these methods and is there an issue running scripts one way or the other?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that in the first case:

```
c:\> python test1.py
c:\> python .\test1.py
```

You're running *python* itself, and then the file is an argument to the interpreter. So *python* will be affected by `PATH`, but the file is relative. Both of these file paths mean to look for it in the same directory, which is the root of C:. Since the file isn't located there, the error results.

The second case:

```
c:\> c:\Python27\Scripts\test1.py
c:\> test1.py
```

It's the file itself being run as an "executable", factoring in `PATH`. On Unix, this would use the *shebang* and invoke the shell in pretty much the same way, however that's not the case on Windows. Instead, it's basically running whatever is associated with the **.py** extension at the OS level, which is likely to invoke a new Python interpreter in a new Window, hence the behavior where it disappears after it's done.

On Windows, since there's no *shebang*, I generally prefer to run the *python* interpreter directly and pass the script as an argument. I would generally switch to the directory the script is located in first. This way it's more shell-centric, and, I think, straightforward.

You can run `pushd .` to save the cwd, and then after `popd` to go back, optionally. That would work in .cmd files and similar, too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `test1.py` is in `C:` and not in `c:\Python27\Scripts`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: the problem of author is the path of script 'test1.py'

Comment: Maybe so, but you're asking for clarification rather than providing an answer to the question.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: my "asking" is not for clarification but for answer the question :)

Comment: The question is: "What is the difference between these methods and is there an issue running scripts one way or the other?" Now look at your "answer". In what way does that answer the question?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: the difference between these methods is the déclaration of position of script test1.py. the first two méthods the script is not in the current path..the second two method the script is in the current path...the third méthod the path of script is absolute